# Prove for any positive integer $k$, there exists $k$ consecutive not powerful integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A powerful number is defined as a number whose prime power factorization has exponents only greater than 1.

While square-free implies not powerful, not powerful does not imply square-free.

I've thought of beginning with the number $n = \prod^{r}_{i = 1} p_{i}$ (where $p_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ prime number) such that $\sum^{r}_{i=r} p_{i} > k$ and creating the sequence of $k$ consecutive squarefree integers by incrementing the number and showing each is squarefree, but I am not able to see a consistent pattern that would make this approach work.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: The usual term for "not powerful" is "squarefree".

Comment: You can always, however, find $k$ consecutive integers **none of which** is square-free.

Comment: Are there infinitely many sets $\{ x,x+1,x+2\}$ that are square free?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Not powerful does not imply square free: 3^2 * 5 is not powerful, but it is also not squarefree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $k$ primes, $p_1,\dots,p_k$, and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find $X$ such that $X+i\equiv p_i\pmod{p_i^2}$. Then the numbers $X+1,\dots,X+k$ will not be powerful.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true for any $k\ge 4$, since at least one of your numbers will then be divisible by $4=2^2$.

Comment: Doesn't this statement contradict the list of all powerful numbers between 1 and 20 listed on wikipedia: 1, 4, 8, 9, 16.

So between 9 and 16, there are 6 consecutive numbers that are not powerful.

Comment: Not sure how this has so many upvotes. It blatantly misunderstands what a squarefull number is and what it means for a number to not be squarefull. A number can have a square factor, and still not be squarefull. $4 \times 3$ is not squarefull, despite being divisible by $4 = 2^2$.